# Wanted to optimize creating Entries using Tkinter

Tags: python, loops, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I passed two hours trying to make this ugly code shorter, in order to get their value right after, 'customscript#' are my entries i want to get the value back by 'customscript#.get()', 'rootfr' is my main frame, s# are variables. So I wanted to know if there was a way to make it with a 'for' loop or something like that, thanks.

```
customscript1 = Entry(rootfr)
customscript1.insert(0, s1)
customscript1.grid(column = 3, row = 1)

customscript2 = Entry(rootfr)
customscript2.insert(0, s1)
customscript2.grid(column = 3, row = 2)

customscript3 = Entry(rootfr)
customscript3.insert(0, s1)
customscript3.grid(column = 3, row = 3)

customscript4 = Entry(rootfr)
customscript4.insert(0, s1)
customscript4.grid(column = 3, row = 4)

customscript5 = Entry(rootfr)
customscript5.insert(0, s1)
customscript5.grid(column = 3, row = 5)

customscript6 = Entry(rootfr)
customscript6.insert(0, s1)
customscript6.grid(column = 3, row = 6)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use `locals()` or `globals()` I guess.

```
local_dict = locals()
for index in xrange(1, 7):
    local_dict['customscript%d' % index] = entry = Entry(rootfr)
    entry.insert(0, s1)
    entry.grid(column = 3, row = index)
```

Functions reference:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#globals

https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#locals

Or you could simply use a list to store all those customscripts, as I seriously doubt you really need to have a bunch of numbered variables. As a rule of thumb, if you find yourself forced to write ugly code, the problem is somewhere in the code architecture.

Comment: Oh thanks @Lav :D, didnt know locals and globals stuff... I'm a beginner I have a lot to learn ! Thank you for the quick answer.

Comment: While technically this works, it's a really bad idea to dynamically generate variables this way. There are much easier ways. I see you warned against that, but by putting the code first in your answer it gives the impression that it's the right solution.

Comment: @BryanOakley, the question was essentially about how to set globals with dynamically generated names, and this was the question that I answered to. Question author may have poor reasons to use this, but his question is going to stay and be visited by other people who may have fully legitimate reasons to use such methods. How is preaching without giving an answer going to be helpful to **them**?

Answer (score 0):

You can store the entries in a list or dictionary. I find dictionaries to be convenient because they can be sparse (ie: you don't have to start counting at zero):

```
entries = {}
for row in range(1,7):
    e = Entry(rootfr)
    e.insert(0, s1)
    e.grid(column = 3, row = 1)
    entries[row] = e
```

Later you can access them via their index:

```
for row in range(1, 7):
    print("row %s has the value %s" % (row, entries[row])
```